# Difficulty with solving sudoku puzzle

Tags: python-2.7

I was stuck solving a sudoku puzzle with python.I am solving it using the method of backtracking error.My Code is implementing this method correctly upto some number of elements.But after some element it is not moving to the next empty cell to implement this,but it is staing at that particular cell.I think my function to check whether a value is valid at a position is working correctly.I was not able to figure out the mistake I was doing. Can someone help me regarding this.

code:

```
from numpy import *
def isValid(matrix,row,col):
    element = matrix[row][col]
    #print element
    #print where(matrix[row,:] == element)
    if len(where(matrix[row,:] == element)[0]) == 1  and len(where(matrix[:,col] == element)[0]) == 1:
        #print 'entered'
        row_type = row%3;col_type =col%3
        row_index = row-row_type;col_index = col-col_type  
        if len(where(matrix[row_index:row_index+3,col_index:col_index+3])[0] == 1):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    else :
        return 0


sudoku = loadtxt('1')
sudoku = array(sudoku,dtype = int)

blankRow,blankCol = where(sudoku == 0)
i=0
while i< len(blankRow):
    print 'i:',i
    #print 'entered'
    while sudoku[blankRow[i],blankCol[i]] < 9:
        #print 'entered',sudoku[blankRow[i],blankCol[i]]
        sudoku[blankRow[i],blankCol[i]] += 1 
        #j = sudoku[blankRow[i],blankCol[i]]
        valid = isValid(sudoku,blankRow[i],blankCol[i])
        if valid == 1:
            break           
    if  sudoku[blankRow[i],blankCol[i]] == 9 and valid != 1:
        print 'entered' #invalid,i:',i,'j',j,'row:',blankRow[i],'col:',blankCol[i]
        sudoku[blankRow[i],blankCol[i]] = 0
        i-= 1 
    i+=1
```

Comment: Try stepping through your code and find where exactly is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your backtracking never works, because you unconditionally add 1 to `i` at the end of the outer loop. I think you want to put that increment in an `else` block, attached to the `if` just above it:

```
if  sudoku[blankRow[i],blankCol[i]] == 9 and valid != 1:
    print 'entered' #invalid,i:',i,'j',j,'row:',blankRow[i],'col:',blankCol[i]
    sudoku[blankRow[i],blankCol[i]] = 0
    i-= 1 
else:         # add this!
    i+=1      # indent this!
```

Note that you might need to add some additional checking to make your code behave properly if it is given an unsolvable puzzle. In that situation, `i` will become negative, as it backtracks past the first position. This won't actually lead to an immediate error, as you can index a list or array with a negative value, but it will eventually raise an exception after trying (and failing) to solve the puzzle again several times.